# Filtering pexpect output

Tags: pexpect

I have a Cisco router and I need to know which interface is used for LAN. This is the **show interface description** output:

```
R1#sho int desc
Interface                      Status         Protocol Description
Em0/0                          admin down     down
Gi0/0                          up             up       LAN
Gi0/1                          up             up       WAN
Gi0/2                          up             up       Crosslink
Gi0/2.100                      up             up       Crosslink
```

I managed to login with pexpect and get the above output into a variable, but I'm not sure how to filter it:

```
execute.send('term len 0\n')
execute.expect(device['name'] + '#')

execute.send('sho int desc\n')
execute.expect(device['name'] + '#')
output = execute.before
```

I would like to have "Gi0/0" as a result.

Could you give me some ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code:

```
    execute.send('sho int desc\n')
    execute.expect(device['name'] + '#')
    output = execute.before

    for line in output.splitlines():
        if re.match('.*LAN.*', line):
            interfaceName = re.findall(r'[^\s]+' ,line)[0]
```

There must be a better solution. If you have any ideas please share them.